# set links visited color to transparent works in firefox but not IE

Tags: internet-explorer, hyperlink

i used this Code, works fine in Firefox, but in IE unvisited links are default blue and visited links are purple? please help,not whats the deal

```
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:transparent;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some googling on this issue shows that IE doesn't support color:transparent.

Try doing this for IE

```
a:link{color: transparent; width: 100%; filter: alpha(opacity=0)}
a:visited{color: transparent;  width: 100%; filter:alpha(opacity=0)}
```

Please do note that providing width seems to be necessary for opacity to take effect

Comment: i tried it but it caused all of my links to disappear. the thing is when i place the color as black it changes in firefox but theres no effect in IE

Comment: yes that is true. Changing only the color when opaity is set would not matter. In that case, the way you change color to black (using javascript, I suppose) you must make opacity 100 too.

Comment: Filters have a significant performance penalty. You'll want to use native opacity instead of a Filter when running on IE9 and above.